# Combinations Of Numbers To Equal One Total

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript I get two numbers let's call them x & y and an array of integers with random int's from 0 - 10 arrayints.

x is the number I'm trying to get by combining y with any of the numbers in arrayints.

> for example: lets say x = 8 and y = 3 and arrayints consists of numbers arrayints(1,7,2,7,4,5)

so x could equal = y + 5
or
x = y + 1 + 4

All the values in x, y and arrayints will be random and always <= 10.

Please advise if more information is needed and everything will be in javascript or jquery no fuss as far as my code goes I will copy and paste but it will just be one blob of incromprehensible letters which are giving me an headache.

```
function makex(x,y) {
//this is how I get the array of random ints <=10
  $("#div").children().each(function(n, i) {
    var id = parseInt(this.id+"");      
  });                           
 }
```

Comment: Only using addition? Subtraction? Other math operators?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In general: add `y` to the array, then find all permutations (google this) and see if each adds up. It's not the most efficient, but it's some and effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution that returns an array of the integers that add up to x, including y (or an empty array if it doesn't exist).  If you want to exclude y, then feel free to make a wrapper for this.

```
function make(x, y, intOptions) {
    var z = x - y    
    if (intOptions.indexOf(z) !== -1) {
        return [y, z];
    } else if (intOptions.length > 1){
        var i = intOptions.length;
        var ans;
        while (i--) {
            ans = make(z, intOptions[i], intOptions.slice(0, i))
            if (ans.length) {
                return [y].concat(ans);
            }
        }        
    }
    return [];
}
```